# How to tell if an outbound email failed in real-time?

Tags: email, email-relay

I have set up an email relay and we are encountering an issue where the email shows up as an outbound message, but there is no indication that it failed. Upon downloading the email log, I can see the email relay returned an error message.

There does not appear to be an object that captures this information, what are my options for identifying this as it happens so that I can notify the associate that sent the mail via updating a field on the case that email is related to or by workflow and email alert that notifies a support team.

Edit:

I have activated bounce management for my emails, but I am not seeing any indicator that it bounced even though the log provides the bounced messsage on the outbound email message. *It's possible I am not familiar with where the bounce indicator is.

Answer (score 1):

You can request that up to five users receive a notification listing all outbound messages that have failed for at least 24 hours. A fresh notification is sent every 24 hours until you cancel the request.

Please refer the further steps on this page - https://sforce.co/2UwA3gM

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for something a little closer to real-time to let the user know the email they sent was not received by the customer.